# Reporting services not showing results in browser but it does on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a strange issue with reporting services, when I preview my report in visual studio it works correctly, but when I run it in the browser, it does not show, it just keeps loading, then loading dissapears and then it's blank, the strangest thing is that if I change the parameters it works, it works for some parameters. Please help!

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I tried google chrome and Internet Explorer, but I was able to find a solution, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue, my report was timing out because the Script manager default time out value is 90 seconds, so I just added AsyncPostBackTimeout="0" to the script manager and now it works like a baby.